# Comprehensive list of Chrome DevTools CSS Selectors

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having problems right now connecting to the chrome-devtools IRC channel or else I would ask this question there first.

Does anyone know where I can find a comprehensive list of the available css selectors used to theme Chrome DevTools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the devtools inspector, you can see all the css files loaded in the sources panel. You can copy the link and view them in your browser (e.g. `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.css`).

However, doing this is rather painstaking.  Alot of people have built themes and isolated the most popular selectors already.  Check out http://www.devthemez.com for pre-made themes.

If you want to get into theme building, take a look at https://github.com/mauricecruz/zero-base-themes.